# How to count occurrences for each year and month 'yyyy-mm' in two columns (including periods in between without occurrences)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to count the number of starts and ends per year and month.

Part of my table looks like this

```
================
YM_START YM_END
================
2014-02  2014-02
2014-11  2014-11
2014-07  2014-09
2014-09  null
null     2014-09
================
```

This will only count the number of starts per year and month ...

```
select count(YM_START), YM_START 
from mytable 
group by YM_START
order by YM_START asc
```

... and it does not include those years and months (between min and max in the records) that I would like to count as zero (for example 2014-03).

From the table above I would like the following result

```
===============================
YYYY-MM NO_OF_STARTS NO_OF_ENDS
2014-02            1          1
2014-03
2014-04
2014-05
2014-06
2014-07            1
2014-08                       
2014-09            1          2
2014-10
2014-11            1          1
===============================
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [make a range of months](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1120618)